# Starting Ubuntu in VirtualBox shows login screen, but after successful login desktop does not get loaded

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, lubuntu, login

I run Lubuntu 14.04 as guest on a Windows 8.1 host.

Everything ran smoothly on a vmdk file that I originally got from vmware workspace.

I tried something out and accidentally created a new machine on the same disk files but never booted into it.

Back on the old vbox config files I can start the machine, reach the login screen, can enter my password and that succeeds. But now, when my desktop should load, I see only the background picture, no icons load, and no start bar loads. I cannot click and drag a semi transparent square, I cannot right click, nothing happens. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not open a terminal.

Can I somehow debug to see what's going on?

the last thing I installed was Android sdk studio. This might have messed with the kernel kvm of virtualbox?

Sadly, there is no snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I damaged my `/etc/environment` or `/etc/sudoers` file by copy pasting text into it using a text editor. The newlines were windows... so basically my path variable didn't work any more!

I managed to fix it by logging in
then pressing

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

then setting path manually again
then fixing everything in vi.